# React Js get params from URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to get url params using react js.
My Route is

```
<Route exact path="/store/product-details/:id" component = {StoreProductDetails} />
```

ProductDetail.js

```
componentDidMount(){
      let id = this.props.match.params.id
      fetch(MyGlobleSetting.url + 'product/'+ id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ singleProduct: json.data }));
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mZKc.png)

Comment: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-pass-multiple-route-parameters-in-a-react-url-path-4b919de0abbe

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `useParams` hook or wrap a class based component with the `withRouter` HOC from react-router. You can see an example in their [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params).

**Using functional components**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

function Child() {
  // We can use the `useParams` hook here to access
  // the dynamic pieces of the URL.
  let { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
     fetch(MyGlobleSetting.url + 'product/'+ id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ singleProduct: json.data }));
  }, [])
}
```

**Using a class component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class myComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
     const {match} = this.props

     fetch(MyGlobleSetting.url + 'product/'+ match.params.id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ singleProduct: json.data }));
  }
}

export default withRouter(Child);
```

Comment: how is it  possible class life-cycle `componentDidMount` work with functional component ?

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I'm so used to functional programming it want straight over my head. I'll fix it now

Comment: i think still wrong, functional component doesn't have `componentDidMount`. Its a lifecycle method of react class component https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: And again you're correct hahahahah That's what I get for doing 3 things at the same time